# how to get current date from server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i want to get the current date from server and my database is on server then whose date mysql now() and CURDATE() function will give, whether of client machine or of server. Please help.
this is what i'hv done

```
insert into admission_fees_structure (Fee_Head_Name , Amount,Created_Date , Created_By) values (feeName, amount, now(),userID);
select name into @result from sims.school_session where YEAR(Start_Date)=YEAR(CURDATE());
```

Comment: When insert use NOW() function, NOW() is on MySql server, Time server and time mysql is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions are executed by MySQL. So they return the date and time of the system running the MySQL process.

Answer (score 30):

There are 8 ways to get the current time:

```
SELECT NOW() FROM DUAL;
   2006-07-01 10:02:41 

SELECT CURRENT_TIME() FROM DUAL;
   10:02:58

SELECT SYSDATE() FROM DUAL;
   2006-07-01 10:03:21 

mysql> SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM DUAL;
   2006-07-01 10:04:03 

SELECT LOCALTIME() FROM DUAL;
   2006-07-01 10:07:37 

mysql> SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP() FROM DUAL;
   2006-07-01 10:08:08 

mysql> SELECT UTC_TIME() FROM DUAL;
   14:09:22 

mysql> SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP() FROM DUAL;
   2006-07-01 14:09:49
```

Answer (score 0):

replace now() to  CURDATE() function ...I also use that code

Comment: will CURDATE() returns the current of server

Comment: u want client current date ?